# How to input R package from local PC directory

Tags: r, installation-package

I need to use a package from Hogg's Introduction to Mathematical Statistics text. It is not found on cranR. R input follows below. Package is in 3.5 directory.

```
library(hmcpkg, lib.loc="C:/Users/mmsta/Documents/R/win-library/3.5")
```

Error message:

```
Error in library(hmcpkg, lib.loc = "C:/Users/mmsta/Documents/R/win-library/3.5") :  ‘hmcpkg’ is not a valid installed package
```

How to do without going to Hogg website when I have the directory hmcpkg on my hard drive? This is a generic question; I have encountered this before. I would also like to avoid the complexity of github.

Thanks.

Mary A. Marion

Comment: Have you installed the package first (before trying to load it)? You can install it from local source, something like `install.packages("C:/Users/mmsta/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/yourpackage.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source")`

Comment: zti,

Your recommended syntax did not work. However, by using the R menu system installing from a local file I was finally able to get the package installed.

2 things are necessary. 
1) be sure the C:/Users/mmsta/Documents/R/win-library/3.5 has been created.
 2) place the tar.gz file in that directory

It's all in the details. Thank you for your reply.

Sincerely,
Mary A. Marion